# Prove that (0,1) ⊆ R and (4,10) ⊆ R have the same cardinality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

Hows does (0,1) and (4,10) both existing as real numbers make it have the same cardinality?

Comment: I swear I've seen this exact question recently.

Answer (score 2):

show $f(x)=6x+4$ is a bijective function

Comment: Can you explain the method you used to get to  f(x)=6x+4f(x)=6x+4 ?

Comment: I saw that the new interval had length 6 instead of 1, so I multiplied by 6.  Then I noticed that it was shifted 4 to the right, so I added 4.